# Angular returned data

Tags: php, angularjs

i am trying to create a service that will return a json data from php api, but instead of return pure json data, the angular seem to return JSON together with its config.

**services.js**

```
.service('DistinctAPIService', function($http){
  var base = 'http://localhost/onseral/api/';
  this.listDistinct = function(table, field){
    return $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: base + '/listDistinct.php',
      params: {
        table: table,
        field: field
      }
    });
  }
})

.controller('DistinctMatcode', function($scope, DistinctAPIService){
  DistinctAPIService.listDistinct('material', 'matcode').then(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  })
})
```

**listdistinct.php**

```
<?php
require_once '/config/dbconfig.php';

$table = $_GET['table'];
$field = $_GET['field'];

GetData($table,$field);

function GetData($tablename,$fieldname) {

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT $fieldname as expr1 FROM $tablename order by expr1 asc";
    try {
        $db = getdb();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
 }
?>
```

instead of returning the correct JSON data, it returned

```
{"data":{"data":[{"expr1":"CFFBPS16"}]},"status":200,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://localhost/onseral/api//listDistinct.php","params":{"table":"material_copy","field":"matcode"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"OK"}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   controller('DistinctMatcode', function($scope, DistinctAPIService){
     DistinctAPIService.listDistinct('material', 'matcode').then(function(response){
     $scope.data = response.data.data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
 })
```

Comment: it does remove the `{"data":` but still got another `{"data":`, i just want to get the result as `[{"expr1":"value"}]

Comment: try this   $scope.data = data.data.data

Comment: Im glad to help u. better use this format. i edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Use **header** function before sending data to the client side.
i modified your **listdistinct.php** file. try it , let me know if issue persist.

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT $fieldname as expr1 FROM $tablename order by expr1 asc";
try {
    $db = getdb();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
```

}
?>

Comment: still the same. actually hadiJZ has give the answer, thank you